# HackerRank- Method calculateSum in class Solution cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

I read many different posts and still don't understand why I get this error when running the below:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void calculateSum(int n){
    for (int i=1;i>11;i++){
        int result=n*i;

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
        scanner.close();
        calculateSum();

    }
}
```

I get the below error:

> Compile Message
>
> Solution.java:26: error: method calculateSum in class Solution cannot
>   be applied to given types;
>           calculateSum();
>           ^   required: int   found: no arguments   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length 1 error Exit Status
>
> 1

I passed a value in the calculateSum() method within the main method and it ran successfully but then it prints no output.

Please help me to understand what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: "I passed a value in the calculateSum() method" - **no, you didn't:** `calculateSum();`

Comment: no, I meant previously I had passed it and it didn't produce the desired outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have given argument in called `int n` in `public static void calculateSum(int n)`. When you call that function into your main function you keep `calculateSum` function as empty. You cannot call like that. There for you have to fill that function with an integer value. You have used to input `int n` in main function. There for

use `calculateSum(n);` instead of `calculateSum();`

I found another error on your code you have used `for (int i=1;i>11;i++)`. In here `i > 11` need correction. It should be `for (int i=1;i<11;i++)` like this

Comment: I get this as output "~ no response on stdout ~"